# nginx does not work properly

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have two websites are deployed with nginx/1.16.1 + php7.3-fpm.

here are config files

website 1:

```
$cat web1.conf
upstream web1 {
    server unix:/run/php/web1.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name web1.com www.web1.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name web1.com www.web1.com;
    ssl_certificate web1/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key web1/ssl.key;
    include conf.d/ssl.conf;
    include conf.d/security.conf;
    include conf.d/general.conf;
    index index.php;
    root /home/user0001/web1;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include             conf.d/php_fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass                    web1;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    include conf.d/wp_security.conf;
}
```

website2

```
$cat web2.conf
upstream web2 {
    server unix:/run/php/web2.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name web2.com www.web2.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name web2.com www.web2.com;
    ssl_certificate web2/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key web2/ssl.key;
    include conf.d/ssl.conf;
    include conf.d/security.conf;
    include conf.d/general.conf;
    index index.php;
    root /home/user0001/web2;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include             conf.d/php_fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass                    web2;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    include conf.d/wp_security.conf;
}
```

wp_security.conf

```
$cat wp_security.conf
    location /wp-admin {
        allow xxx.x.xxx.xx/32;
        deny all;
        error_page 403 = @wp_admin_ban;
    }
    location /admin {
        allow xxx.x.xxx.xx/32;
        deny all;
        error_page 403 = @wp_admin_ban;
    }
    location /wp-login.php {
        allow xxx.x.xxx.xx/32;
        deny all;
        error_page 403 = @wp_admin_ban;
    }
    location @wp_admin_ban {
        rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$host permanent;
    }
```

I used 3G/4G to test:

1. goto https://web1.com/wp-login.php it redirect properly to
   https://web1.com
2. goto https://web1.com/wp-admin/ it redirect
   properly to https://web1.com
3. **goto https://web2.com/wp-login.php it
   still load this page. IT DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY**
4. goto https://web2.com/wp-admin/ it redirect
   properly to https://web1.com

Anyone know why? and how to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: My guess, actually 1. is just your browser cache, because you config shouldn’t redirect any *.php request

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes, it caches. Do you know why it don't work like location /wp-admin?

Comment: Check out docs https://nginx.org/r/location